# Uploading shp, kml, csv, gml using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, software-recommendations, browser

I'm using openlayers 2.12 and I'm wondering how could upload shp, kml, csv, gml into the browser, just as a temporary layer wich user could see it.

Is there any library or way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the FileAPI:
http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Here is one example:
http://renevier.net/misc/mapfileapi.html

If you need a kml file to test:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/kml/sundials.kml

And here the browsers that support the fileapi:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

The same as jsfiddle for own tests:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/v0nkgebh/

Comment: thanks @Thomas! You know some tool to do it with shapefile? (this format I'm really interested in)

Comment: You could use this: https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson but kml / geojson are better formats for this reading them at clientside...